# How to implement AJAX communication protocol in Django the OOP way: class-based "view" without the actual view, only JsonResponses

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I have worked a little with both class-based and function-based views in Django. I currently have a URL (let's say /backend) that is mapped to my function. It's only meant to be accessed by POST AJAX requests (I have corresponding checks in the function). The function analyzes incoming data and returns some other data in the form of JSON document. However, the function is not that comfortable and I would much rather have a class that does that. I'm new to Django, are there some "standard" ways of implementing a template-less view that's only meant to return JSON based on input JSON?

Comment: Have you checked out the Django REST framework?

Comment: I have not, but I've heard of it. I'll definitely check it out, but wanted to make sure there is nothing in Django out of the box first. I guess Django REST framework is something I'll have to learn sooner or later, so thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. You can certainly use Django class-based views for this; exactly where are you having problems?

Comment: I don't need an actual view = template. I need to process incoming JSON and return another JSON. So it's not exactly a class-based "view", that's why I was wondering if there is something designed specifically for this use case in Django.

Comment: Nope, no generic class exists for this purpose, so you have to design your own function with @require_POST() decorator or write class-based view with @method_decorator(require_POST()) or explicitly write raising 403 / 404 / 405 erros

Comment: Views are not templates in Django; they are what is known in other frameworks as controllers. It is perfectly possible to have a class-based view with no template.

Comment: Yeap, it was a bad place to put the equal sign. So a subclass of TemplateView with template_name = None should pretty much cover my goal, right?

Comment: Or just use the base [View class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#view).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer! Appreciate your help